# Kubuntu 16.04.1 (plasma 5.6.5) compositor glitching

Tags: kubuntu, kde, opengl, compositing

Usually, when I'm watching youtube, little black boxes flash everywhere on the screen and it's really annoying. Changing the compositor settings to full screen repaints and opengl 3.1 seemed to help, but the issues keep coming back. I'm thinking of upgrading Plasma to 5.7 but people say its unstable.

I have an Intel HD Graphics 4400 with the standard open-source drivers.

Comment: What graphics card and what driver are you using?

Comment: How do I find this? I do know I have an Intel HD Graphics 4400 but I do not know the driver.

Comment: If you have Intel then you have the standard open source drivers available for your Ubuntu version. Shouldn't be a problem. The question was only to gather important information for troubleshooting and the answer should be edited by you to include the information about the graphics card you just provided in the comment.